# How to track progress of an iOS app installation on device

Tags: ios

I want to track the installation progress of an iOS app on iOS device and also I want to be notified when the installation is complete. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no real way:
your app is sandboxed and there is no way to track filesystem changes / app installations outside your sandbox.

now if the app to track is supporting a url scheme and your app would be running while it installs you can poll the os for the ability of that URL scheme so you get YES when it installs.

note: this only works very limited. you must know the app's url scheme and ios must keep your app running

note 2: on a jailbroken device this looks different BTW ;)